# Leprechaun custom field mapping not working, always outputs field type as string

Tags: helix, code-generation, leprechaun

I'm using Leprechaun for code generation and the custom field mapping I'm trying to implement isn't working. The field is generated as type String in every case, so I know the custom mapping is failing but I do not know why. I've tried the following variations:

```
<metadataGenerator type="Leprechaun.MetadataGeneration.StandardTemplateMetadataGenerator, Leprechaun" singleInstance="true">
    <fieldType id="{ae1b2067-94a6-4357-a997-00a5052a98fa}" type="I_AssociateBio" />
</metadataGenerator>

<metadataGenerator type="Leprechaun.MetadataGeneration.StandardTemplateMetadataGenerator, Leprechaun" singleInstance="true">
    <fieldType id="{ae1b2067-94a6-4357-a997-00a5052a98fa}" type="MySite.Feature.AssociateBio.I_AssociateBio" />
</metadataGenerator>

<metadataGenerator type="Leprechaun.MetadataGeneration.StandardTemplateMetadataGenerator, Leprechaun" singleInstance="true">
    <fieldType id="{ae1b2067-94a6-4357-a997-00a5052a98fa}" type="custom=MySite.Feature.AssociateBio.I_AssociateBio" />
</metadataGenerator>
```

I can tell that it's getting picked up, because firstly, the field is a Droplink so without the custom mapping it outputs as a Guid; and secondly, it shows the Field Type from my mapping in the metadata:

```
    /// Represents Person field
    /// <para>Field Type: custom=MySite.Feature.AssociateBio.I_AssociateBio</para>  
    /// <para>ID: {ae1b2067-94a6-4357-a997-00a5052a98fa}</para> 
    /// <para>Section: Employee Spotlight</para>
    /// </summary>
    [SitecoreField(FieldName = IEmployeeSpotlightConstants.Person_FieldName)]
    string Person { get; set; }/// <summary>
```

I cannot get it to output `MySite.Feature.AssociateBio.I_AssociateBio Person { get; set; }`

I_AssociateBio is in another project, but it's referenced in the EmployeeSpotlight project, and when I manually change the type of the field to `I_AssociateBio Person` it's valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Leprechaun.config file, you'll see that the example above the metadata generator shows a "droptree". What "type" is referring to in this case is the Sitecore field type, not a C# class type

```xml
<fieldType id="{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}" type="droptree" />
```

In the csx file for your codegen template, there's a mapping of Sitecore field types to concrete classes: [GlassMapper.csx (line 145)](https://github.com/blipson89/Leprechaun/blob/2.2.2/src/Leprechaun.CodeGen.Roslyn/Scripts/GlassMapper.csx#L145-L205). If the type doesn't match, it'll return string.

What you need to do is define a custom type on the fieldtype as you did above:

```xml
<fieldType id="{ae1b2067-94a6-4357-a997-00a5052a98fa}" type="associatebio" />
```

and then add a line in your `GlassMapper.csx`:

```csharp
case "associatebio":
  return "MySite.Feature.AssociateBio.I_AssociateBio";
```